# regexp symfony2 + javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, symfony

I'm having an issue with regexp.

I have my constraints into a yml file for symfony2:

```
pattern: '^\w+$'
```

then my front gets this validation and javascript turns it into a regexp like this:

```
var myRegex = new RegExp(constraint[0]);
```

In this case the regexp created by JS looks like this:

```
RegExp /^\w+$^/
```

which is fine in javascript.

However when I use the validator component of symfony I get an error

```
Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found
```

I understand that it's because in PCRE I need a delimiter.
But then If I add / / to get:

```
pattern: '/^\w+$/'
```

it works in php but not in JS anymore.

Is my thinking correct?

Is there a functionality in JS that I should use, or is it an inherent issue to javascript and I should resolve of using a library ?

I could trick by just removing the first & last char of the PCRE regex...

Comment: Can you use `javascriptVariable.match(constraint[0])` instead of `new RegExp(constraint[0])`? That should work with the slashes